# Is there a variant of f in vim to only match the first character in a word?

Tags: vim

I'm editing prose in vim, and f is a quick way to move, but it would be quicker still if I could limit f to matching initial characters. I know about w and e, and I use those, too, but they aren't great for long lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could always just use normal searching.

```
/\<f
```

Would search from the current to the next word that starts with f. If you wanted to you could make a mapping for it using `getchar()`. An example of this would be

```
:nnoremap <expr> <f2> '/\<' . nr2char(getchar()) . '<CR>'
```

Which would map `<f2><char>` to jump to the next inputed char.

Comment: Excellent. I like it so much, I remapped it to f, not f2. I also added a remap to <CR> to clear the highlighting, because I can't find that as an option.